# Make UIView behind transparent UIView invisible

Tags: iphone, uiview, transparency

I have a transparent view with alpha set to 0.3, and behind it there are some views,
is there any option in IOS to set some of the views that are behind my transparent view to hidden?

I need when half of the view is behind the transparent, and the other half is not, to show only half of the view

Answer (score 1):

you can hide it after making IBOutlet connection

```
[yourView setHidden:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `hidden` property of the unwanted views to `YES` if you want to hide them.

You can set the alpha to 0.

You can also `[myView removeFromSuperView]` if it makes sense.

Comment: I need when half of the view is behind the transparent, and the other half is not, the show only half of the view

Comment: Ahh ok... check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8552073/draw-a-shadow-which-is-hidden-under-the-semi-transparent-view