# Shadow inside text on NSTextField/NSTextFieldCel

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-graphics, shadow, nstextfield

I've been trying for a day or two to try and get a shadow to draw inside the text of an NSTextField (and making the foreground color transparent, so all you see is a shadow inside the text). I've yet to achieve a desirable and practical result. The only success I had with this was transforming the text into an `NSBezerPath`, subtracting it from the frame of the NSTextFieldCell and clipping using the `setClip` method (`addClip` does not suffice in this case, it leaves the background painted). Unfortunately, converting the text to an `NSBezerPath` makes the edges of the text look jagged and overly straightened. Is there an efficient and decent way to achieve this using CoreGraphics masks and clipping because I am unable to achieve this.

A very similar effect of what I would be looking for is in the Xcode IDE, if you don't have a debug session open and go to the debugger navigator it says "No Debug Session" in a subclassed NSTextField that draws the text with a shadow inside it. That is pretty nearly what I am after. Any insight on where to start and how to do this would be great.

A paste bin my current code (working, but sub-optimal, & non-working): http://pastebin.com/4pTv8ZWm

Comment: I thought it was easy, but the problem is that when you draw a shadow id the text has an alpha value of 0, the shadow is not drawn. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170678/ios-core-graphics-draw-only-shadows-of-a-cgpath

Comment: Ok, I think there is some slight miscommunication. I am trying to not use CGPath/NSBezierPath as paths make the text jagged looking because they are anti-aliased differently than text. I did get it working using bezier paths but the text looks really bad, which is why I was searching for a better method.

Answer (score 1):

Have you played around with the shadow property of NSTextField in IB? You should be able to get pretty close using a slightly offset shadow effect on the text with the right blend of alpha transparency.

Comment: This would only work for  outside shadows. The alpha transparency blending [of the text color] would be an issue because it needs to be zero.

Comment: I'm not sure if I should be shocked (or not) that Apple would go through such difficulty to create a label that is shown 10% of the time in the IDE that most Apple users wouldn't ever touch. I'm wondering if they just have a custom font they use for that text....

Comment: I doubt it, but it is possible. I'd check with F-Script but it keeps crashing Xcode, so I'm unable to tell.