# Core Graphics - How to draw a shadow without drawing a line?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics

Take a look at this code:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
  [super drawRect:rect];

  CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

  CGSize  myShadowOffset = CGSizeMake (-10,  15);

  CGContextSaveGState(context);

  CGContextSetShadow (context, myShadowOffset, 5);

  CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 4.0);
  CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context,
                                 [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
  CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(60,170,200,200);
  CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, rectangle);
  CGContextStrokePath(context);
  CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
```

what it does it draws a circle and a shadow for this circle. However i can't make my mind how to draw only shadow without drawing circle's line? How do i do that? Answers to similar questions here on SO didn't help me

Comment: What happens if you stroke/fill your circle with a completely transparent colour? `[[NSColor clearColor] GCColor]`

Comment: nothing happens. i tried it. just nothing

Comment: You can try `CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor clearColor].CGColor);`

Comment: @Manixate as i said above it draws nothing

Comment: Try this may be `CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 0.0);`

Comment: @Manixate it also produces nothing unfortunately

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170678/ios-core-graphics-draw-only-shadows-of-a-cgpath have you tried this?

Comment: @Manixate i have. nothing as well. blank screen))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try the following:

```
//If you would like your shadow color to be blue, change it to blue.
CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, CGSizeMake(-10.0f,  15.0f), 5.0f, [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, self.backgroundColor.CGColor);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

I just ran a test on it; and the effect seems desirable.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 11):

I was able to achieve this using stroke color **white**, and blend mode **multiply**:

```
// ...
context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.white.cgColor)
context.setShadow(offset: CGSize.zero, blur: 8.0, color: UIColor.black.cgColor)
context.setBlendMode(.multiply)
context.addPath(...) <--- ADD YOUR PATH HERE
context.strokePath()
// ...
```

It draws only the shadow, without the stroke.

Another approach would be to just draw the line and blur it.

Comment: That is very clever, been looking for a solution to this for ages.

Comment: **NOTE** only if the background is white !!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to render the shadow only. The way is background color, shadow color agnostic.

The gist is

1. add a big horizontal offset to the `shadow` you want to render. So that the shadow is separated out from the shadow shape.
2. Translate the context with a negative same horizontal offset, so  that the shadow shape is moved out of the rendering area, and the shadow is moved back.
3. Render normally, you will get the shadow rendering only.

Example code:

```swift
func normalShadowRendering() {
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

    // the shape, a triangle
    let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
    bezierPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 32))
    bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 16, y: 0))
    bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 32, y: 32))
    bezierPath.close()

    // set shadow
    context.setShadow(offset: CGSize(width: 4, height: 4), blur: 8.0, color: UIColor.black.cgColor)

    // render the shape with shadow
    context.addPath(bezierPath.cgPath)
    UIColor.red.setStroke()
    context.setLineWidth(4)
    context.strokePath()
  }
```

The rendering result is:
[image]

```swift
func shadowOnlyRendering() {
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

    // the shape, a triangle
    let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
    bezierPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 32))
    bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 16, y: 0))
    bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 32, y: 32))
    bezierPath.close()

    // set shadow
    // `drawingRect` is the canvas rect
    // add the canvas width extra horizontal offset, so that
    // shadow is separated out
    context.setShadow(offset: CGSize(width: 4 + drawingRect.width, height: 4), blur: 8.0, color: UIColor.black.cgColor)

    // compensate the extra horizontal offset added to the shadow
    // so that the shadow is rendered at correct place, and the 
    // main shape is moved out of the canvas.
    context.translateBy(x: -drawingRect.width, y: 0)

    // render the shadow only
    // shape is out of the canvas
    context.addPath(bezierPath.cgPath)
    UIColor.red.setStroke()
    context.setLineWidth(4)
    context.strokePath()
}
```

The rendering result is:
[image]